# incompatible types: Intent cannot be converted to Callback

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

```
else if (!(email.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()))
                {
                    mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign Up Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            else{
                                startActionMode(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));

                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your confused `startActionMode` with `startActivity`. To send user to next activity after authentication done use following code :

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
```

[Action Mode](https://medium.com/over-engineering/using-androids-actionmode-e903181f2ee3) :

it just provides a bit of temporary system UI that displays a menu of contextual actions.